# I marked my question as duplicate but it was put on hold as too broad

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, on-hold

I asked a question on StackOverflow and after some time I found a duplicate of my own question. I thought it would be fair to mark my own question as a duplicate and I did. However, my question was put on hold as `too broad` which is something I would never want to do and it looks like I am one of the people who voted for it. If someone finds my question now it is impossible for him/her to reach the real answer. Why aren't they being counted separately? Such as;

Too Broad Votes = 4,
Duplicate Votes = 1

Even though I don't think my question was too broad, I've rewritten the whole question from scratch and nominated it to reopen. Are the voters now aware that my question has been edited?

**My question:**

[Authentication events (such as login failure) in spring security oauth2 doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589895/authentication-events-such-as-login-failure-in-spring-security-oauth2-doesnt)

**1st duplicate:**

[How to set exception handler in spring security oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102984/how-to-set-exception-handler-in-spring-security-oauth2)

I mentioned about this 1st duplicate in my own question because it had no answer.

**2nd duplicate:**

[@EventListener for AuthenticationSuccessEvent or InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent not fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076500/eventlistener-for-authenticationsuccessevent-or-interactiveauthenticationsucces)

I found the 2nd duplicate after I asked my own question. Even though I did a search on stackoverflow before asking mine, I couldn't find the 2nd duplicate because title, description and even the tagging is done poorly. Important keywords are not mentioned. I've come across this one by a coincidence, not by searching stackoverflow. But the real value lies here. The answer exactly solves these three problems above.

To summarize;

1- Why aren't the votes being counted separately as I've mentioned above?

2- Are the voters now aware that I edited the question?

3- What should I do to make my question open again? I have edited my question according to the rules, but how can it be reopened if no one sees my editing?

4- What should I do to reach the other voters and make them mark as a duplicate?

Comment: 1. the majority of voters win; 2. no; 3. post on meta (but better had been the site meta, not the network meta); 4. You don't, once it enters the re-open queue 3K-ers will vote or not and/or they respond based on this question.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. For (1) I think, it still would have been better to put it on hold when one of the reasons reach to 5, not the sum. I will be looking for stackoverflow meta. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just FYI: I asked in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41895604#41895604) if we would like to do a re-open dance but none were interested as we don't really see where the value is. So if you are going to re-post on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) you have to make even more effort to get it handled by the community to your liking, unless a mod agrees with you and takes the honors.

Comment: @rene thanks a lot for your effort. It has to be a wall of code because of spring security. There are also lots of code if you look at the duplicates. I find it strange that they didn't get tagged as too broad, actually all three questions are very very similar.

Comment: Ok I will leave a final comment on my question pointing out to the duplicate that has the best answer. I hope someone finds the way from there. There is nothing else to do at the moment. Lesson learned. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Yeah, we don't have many spring tag followers around. I assume if you attract the right crowd they can value your question and judge the duplicates. You're welcome.